# How to get the cluster ID's from a scikit learn model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, k-means

I completed my code in scikit-learn and need to pass my code to the data engineer.

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 5, init = 'k-means++', random_state = 42)
y_kmeans = kmeans.fit_predict(X)
```

The goals is to segment the population using k-means. I need the output to ID 5 clusters onto a report (CSV) so its in its own column. How do I go about this after I fit the model ?

Answer (score 1):

You can save your model as a pickle and give the pickle file to the data engineer

```
import pickle
filename = 'your_model.pkl'
pickle.dump(model, open(filename, 'wb'))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have your data X already in a dataframe `df`, then it is straightforward to add a column with the cluster ID; here is an example with dummy 2D data and 2 clusters:

```python
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

# dummy data:
X = np.array([[10, 2], [1, 4], [1, 0],
              [1, 2], [10, 4], [10, 0]])
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1':X[:,0],'Column2':X[:,1]})

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, init = 'k-means++', random_state=42).fit(X)
kmeans.labels_
# array([1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1])

df['clusterID'] = kmeans.labels_
print(df)
```

The result is

```python
   Column1  Column2  clusterID
0       10        2          1
1        1        4          0
2        1        0          0
3        1        2          0
4       10        4          1
5       10        0          1
```